# Cycle2 with DIV Elements - First element at start is unaligned vertically

Tags: css, carousel, jquery-cycle2

This is the problem that I'm running into:

```
[jsfiddle.net/8Md96/][1]
```

As you can see, when the Cycle2 starts, the first element is unaligned, after the second item is passing, the align is "seems to be fixed. I tried to see what was causing it but I can't find anything. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add overflow:hidden to .cycleDemo